# npm issues with uglify-js

Tags: raspberry-pi, node.js, npm

I'm trying to use node.js to run a project on my Raspberry Pi (following this guide: http://blog.donaldderek.com/2013/06/build-your-own-google-tv-using-raspberrypi-nodejs-and-socket-io/ ) and I've run into a bit of a problem with npm. When I try `npm install` I get a bunch of errors, the first of which being `npm ERR! error installing uglify-js@2.2.5`

`npm ls` gives

```
npm WARN jade * Unmet dependency in /home/pi/app/RaspberryPiTV
npm WARN base64id 0.1.0 Unmet dependency in /home/pi/app/RaspberryPiTV/node_modules/socket.io
npm WARN policyfile 0.0.4 Unmet dependency in /home/pi/app/RaspberryPiTV/node_modules/socket.io
npm WARN socket.io-client 0.9.11 Unmet dependency in /home/pi/app/RaspberryPiTV/node_modules/socket.io
GoogleTV-rPi@1.2.1 /home/pi/app/RaspberryPiTV
âââ¬ express@3.1.1
â âââ buffer-crc32@0.2.1
â âââ commander@0.6.1
â âââ¬ connect@2.7.4
â â âââ buffer-crc32@0.1.1
â â âââ bytes@0.2.0
â â âââ formidable@1.0.11
â â âââ pause@0.0.1
â â âââ qs@0.5.1
â âââ cookie@0.0.5
â âââ cookie-signature@0.0.1
â âââ debug@0.7.2
â âââ fresh@0.1.0
â âââ methods@0.0.1
â âââ mkdirp@0.3.5
â âââ range-parser@0.0.4
â âââ¬ send@0.1.0
â   âââ mime@1.2.6
âââ UNMET DEPENDENCY jade *
âââ omxcontrol@0.0.1
âââ¬ socket.io@0.9.14
â âââ UNMET DEPENDENCY base64id 0.1.0
â âââ UNMET DEPENDENCY policyfile 0.0.4
â âââ UNMET DEPENDENCY socket.io-client 0.9.11
âââ uglify-js@1.3.5  extraneous
```

And here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "GoogleTV-rPi",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.1",
    "jade": "*",
    "socket.io": "0.9.14",
    "omxcontrol": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "*"
  }
}
```

Node version is v0.10.7
npm version is 1.1.4

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or if there are any workarounds?

Comment: I have the same issue and I think I narrowed it down to being uglify-js' fault, as my log seems to be a little more verbose. I'll keep you posted

Comment: just drop the jade dependency. worked for me.